# Direct sum A+B versus $A\cup B$ and Brunn-Minkowski inequality

Tags: real-analysis

So by the Brunn-Minkowski we have $m(A+B)^{\frac{1}{n}}\geq m(A)^{\frac{1}{n}}+m(B)^{\frac{1}{n}}$

But for lebesgue measures $m(A\cup B)\leq m(A)+m(B)$

So I was wondering what is the relation between $A+B$ and $A\cup B$. Are there any conditions?

For example if $0\in A\cap B$ then $A\cup B\subset A+B\Rightarrow 
[m(A)+m(B)]^\frac{1}{n}\geq m(A+B)^{\frac{1}{n}}\geq m(A)^{\frac{1}{n}}+m(B)^{\frac{1}{n}}$

Is there any theorem relating $A+B$ and $A\cup B$?

Comment: I don't think you can get the second last inequality? $A\cup B \subset A+B$ only mean $m(A\cup B) \leq m(A+B)$.

Comment: measures are countably subadditive.

Comment: I guess all the real analysis people are studying for exams.

Comment: Let $A =B = [-1, 1]^2$. So $m(A) = m(B) = 4$. While $A+B = [-2, 2]$ has measure $16$. Your second last inequality is not correct.

Comment: The deepest fact about the relation of $A+B$ and $A\cup B$ is the statement you have already made, after "For example".